# Where can I find the Docs for mac terminal commands, specifically 'open'

Tags: macos, terminal

Zsh

MAC 11.4

I am writing an alias that opens two new Terminals and runs a script in each.
The command for opening a new terminal I have found to work is:

```
open -a Terminal -n; *program*
```

I am trying to locate the docs on this command to better understand what '-a' and '-n' mean and how I can use it better, but am unsure of where to look? Is it built in Zsh, applescript, etc???

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ IcyIcicle, Thanks. So these commands are part of a 'BSD' package for all unix systems?

Comment: I am not sure, but here is the page for [linux man](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/man1.html) and [macos man](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/system.3.html). So it looks like it is on both. I am not sure about the 'BSD' package though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man` shows the manual pages of a command.

The syntax is `man open`. You can even do `man man` with this result.

```
NAME
       man - format and display the on-line manual pages

SYNOPSIS
       man [-acdfFhkKtwW] [--path] [-m system] [-p string] [-C config_file] [-M pathlist] [-P pager] [-B browser] [-H htmlpager] [-S section_list] [section] name ...

DESCRIPTION
       man formats and displays the on-line manual pages.  If you specify section, man only looks in that section of the manual.  name is normally the name of the manual page, which
       is typically the name of a command, function, or file.  However, if name contains a slash (/) then man interprets it as a file specification, so that you can do  man  ./foo.5
       or even man /cd/foo/bar.1.gz.

       See below for a description of where man looks for the manual page files.
```